# System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-identity, .net-7.0

I am unable to log into my application. I am using postman to post a request to my auth controller with username and password however I get the below error message. I recently upgraded from .net 5 to 6 and then to 7.

```
> System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.SignInManager`1[software.API.Models.User]' while attempting to activate 'software.API.Controllers.AuthController'.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ActivatorUtilities.GetService(IServiceProvider sp, Type type, Type requiredBy, Boolean isDefaultParameterRequired)
   at lambda_method23(Closure, IServiceProvider, Object[])
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider.<>c__DisplayClass6_0.<CreateControllerFactory>g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
--- End of stack trace from previous location ---
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeFilterPipelineAsync>g__Awaited|20_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, Object state, Boolean isCompleted)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.<InvokeAsync>g__Logged|17_1(ResourceInvoker invoker)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> 
> HEADERS
> ======= Accept: */* Connection: keep-alive Host: localhost:5000 User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.31.1 Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
> Content-Type: application/json Content-Length: 95 Postman-Token:
> 74973643-8422-46d3-b96b-7c2dfdd9c92e.API.Models.User]
```

IdentityServiceExtension and ApplicationServiceExtensions run initially in the program.cs file.

ApplicationServiceExtensions

```
    public static class ApplicationServiceExtensions
    {
        public static IServiceCollection AddApplicationServices(this IServiceCollection services,
           IConfiguration config)
        {
           services.AddCors();

           services.AddScoped<ITokenService, TokenService>();
           services.AddScoped<ITaskScheduleRepository, TaskScheduleRepository>();
           services.AddScoped<IUserRepository, UserRepository>();
           services.AddScoped<INotesRepository, NotesRepository>();
           services.AddScoped<IAttachmentFileRepository, AttachmentFileRepository>();
           services.AddScoped<ICustomerRepository, CustomerRepository>();
           services.AddScoped<IReportRepository, ReportRepository>();
        
           services.AddHttpContextAccessor();

           services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());

           return services;
       }
    }
```

IdentityServiceExtension

```
    public static class IdentityServiceExtensions
    {
     public static IServiceCollection AddIdentityServices(this IServiceCollection services,
        IConfiguration config)
    {

        services.AddIdentityCore<User>(opt =>
        {
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opt.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 3;
            opt.Password.RequireDigit = true;
            opt.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
            opt.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
            opt.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        })

            .AddRoles<Role>()
            .AddRoleManager<RoleManager<Role>>()
            .AddRoleValidator<RoleValidator<Role>>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<DataContext>();


              services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
                options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,                 
                    IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding
                        .UTF8.GetBytes("test")),
                    ValidateIssuer = false,
                    ValidateAudience = false
                };

                options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                {
                    OnMessageReceived = context => 
                    {
                        var accessToken = context.Request.Query["access_token"];

                        var path = context.HttpContext.Request.Path;
                        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(accessToken) && path.StartsWithSegments("/hubs"))
                        {
                            context.Token = accessToken;
                        }

                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                };
            });

        services.AddAuthorization(opt => 
        {
            opt.AddPolicy("RequireAdminRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin"));
            opt.AddPolicy("ModeratePhotoRole", policy => policy.RequireRole("Admin", "Moderator"));
        });

        return services;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I think a ````.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>()```` line is missing. Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identitybuilderextensions.addsigninmanager?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 0):

```
.AddSignInManager<SignInManager<User>>()
```

The code above was missing from `IdentityServiceExtensions`